# Sometimes a weird suspicious notification sound is played on my PC

Tags: privacy, spyware, remote-desktop, windows-7, rat

I bought a second hand HP Compaq 8100 Elite SFF PC several years ago with Windows 7 home basic preinstalled on it.

Occasionally a weird suspicious notification sound is played once for a session on it which I cannot find its source... I don't know exactly why but it seems to me very like a remote login/access notification sound.

How can I discover what's the source of that sound?

How can I check my PC for possible hidden remote access tools?

Comment: *"I don't know exactly why but it seems to me very like a remote login/access notification sound."* - why should this make a sound at all? Why should make it exactly this sound? This question looks for me like trying to blame some RAT for no reason apart of "don't know anything else". As for finding out source of some sound - this is not about information security, i.e. off-topic here. You might try instead superuser.com.

Comment: Step 1: rule out mundane problems. Step 2: if you're sure it's an infection, trying to hunt it down is going to be tough unless a security tool finds it for you, so just rebuild the machine.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich have u ever heard of things like IPMI (Intelligent Platform Management Interface
) and AMT (Intel Active Management Technology)? I thought that sound could be related to those technologies